# Ok to use meta noindex on 404 pages?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, 404, noindex

I have a custom `404.html` file on my website that gets served with a 404 status code when a URL is not found, standard stuff. But if you visit the exact path `/404.html` on the server, the server says "hey, there's actually a file there" and shows you the 404 page but without the 404 status code.

I wanted to make sure that the `/404.html` path doesn't get accidentally indexed in search, so I added a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` tag to it.

Of course, that means that my nonexistant URLs also have the `meta noindex` tag as part of the 404 page. Is there any way that the presence of this `meta noindex` tag could cause an issue for search engines / crawlers, or is this setup totally fine?

Comment: Alternately you could name the file `/404-3pAhD3tM.html` which would be unlikely to ever to get crawled unless you linked to it or had directory indexes on.

Comment: I also suspect that if Google did crawl `/404.html` it would treat it as a "soft 404" because it presumably has "Page Not Found" in the title and H1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no problem having a `meta noindex` tag on the 404 page, to prevent 200 OK responses being indexed.

If this was a PHP page then you could obviously just send a 404 Not Found header as part of the standard response - to make sure that it *always* returns a 404.

If you are on the Apache web server then you could also use `.htaccess` (mod_rewrite) to force any direct requests to `404.html` to also trigger a 404 and still serve your custom error document. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^404\.html$ - [R=404]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive that checks the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is required if you want your custom 404 to be served (so that it only applies to direct requests). Otherwise, there will likely be a rewrite loop (500 error) when trying to serve the custom error document and you'll see the standard server generated 404 response (but it's still a 404).

Comment: Thank you for the good ideas. For my hosting setup it's easiest to just leave the `meta noindex` in place, so it's good to know it won't cause any issues if I do.

Comment: Also for Nginx, to return 404 on direct access to your custom 404 file, you could add `error_page 404 =200 404.php`

Comment: @PelinCanikli But doesn't that just override the 404 HTTP status and send a "200 OK" HTTP status instead for everything that should be a 404? (Unless `404.php` itself overrides the response status... But that's not possible in the OPs case since they aren't using PHP. Also, shouldn't that be `/404.php`, not `404.php`?)